# Remove Registry Keys for Windows Phone 7 Emulator

Tags: registry, windows-installer, windows-phone-7

I am trying to get the updated Windows Phone 7 tools installed, but can't get rid of the old ones.  The uninstaller wouldn't run, so I had to try more extreme means.  I got everything removed except for "Microsoft Windows Phone Emulator x64".  Does anyone know what vm_web.exe (the tool installer) is checking for (registry, file, etc.) that prevents the installer from running.

I tried Aaron Stebner's [clean up tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/pages/9544320.aspx), and it helped a lot, but couldn't get rid of the emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by reinstalling windows.

Answer (score 1):

I would try removing the emulator by going into Computer>C:>Program Files (x86)>Microsoft SDKs> and deleting the folder named Windows Phone.

After that, go to Computer>C:>Program Files (x86)> and deleting the folder named Microsoft XDE.

That should remove the emulator entirely.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I ended up reinstalling the windows to get it fixed.